# aurelia-fetch-client create request headers on the fly

Tags: object, header, aurelia

I am using aurelia-fetch-client to send some data to a web-api (in a register method).

```
headers: Headers;

register() {

    this.headers = new Headers();

    this.headers.append("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    this.httpClient.fetch("api/Account/Register", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: this.email,
            password: this.password
        }),

        headers: this.headers
    })
}
```

As you see, I want to update the headers of my request (in that append method call) and for doing that I need to create my own Headers object, to call the method append on it and then to assign it to the headers property of my request. I want to do that directly in the request body: instead of writing

```
 headers: this.headers
```

I want to write something like:

```
 headers: { 
    append("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 }
```

or something like:

```
  headers: new Headers().append(..)
```

The idea is to avoid declaring a new object for storing my headers. 
How can I do that?

Thank you respectfully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just pass in an JS object literal with the keys and values directly to the `headers` property:

```
this.httpClient.fetch("api/Account/Register", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }),

    headers: {
       "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
});
```

Or you can also crate the `Headers` object pre-filled with your custom headers:

```
this.httpClient.fetch("api/Account/Register", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
    }),

    headers: new Headers({
       "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
});
```

See also the [headers related test of the plugin](https://github.com/aurelia/fetch-client/commit/b70ac032dd2e0af74ecaa1eea8965bc6e9677a7f#L180-L237).

Comment: This is correct. If you're only setting the `content-type` to `application/json`, you can also check out the `json` helper, which takes care of setting the header for you. `import {json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client', then use `body: json({ email: this.email, password: this.password })`. See also https://gist.github.com/bryanrsmith/14caed2015b9c54e70c3#helpers, which will move into official documentation soon.