# Aurelia - Fetch - getting error TS2345 headers: { "Content-Type": string; }; }' is not assignable

Tags: aurelia

This was working and now for some unknown reason its giving this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ method: string; body: string; headers: { "Content-Type": string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInit | undefined'.
>     Type '{ method: string; body: string; headers: { "Content-Type": string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'RequestInit'.
>       Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
>         Type '{ "Content-Type": string; }' is not assignable to type 'Headers | string[][] | undefined'.
>           Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"Content-Type"' does not exist in type 'Headers | string[][] | undefined'.

Its on a FETCH and if I comment out the..

```
headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    }
```

entry out the application displays again but of course it cant get to the server with the correct content type.

I have no idea why this is now erroring on this and I have looked on SO for something similar but cant find a thing.

Here is the method:

```
submitLogin() {
if (this.controller.validate()) {
  // Lets do a fetch!

  this.login.Username = this.username;
  this.login.Password = this.password;

  const task = fetch("/api/jwt", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.login),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"   //  HERE!
    }
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.tokenService.saveJWT(data);
      this.userService.saveUserName();
      this.router.navigate("home");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.tokenService.clearJWT();
    });
}
```

}

Does anybody know why this is happening and more importantly how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

OK for some reason this just stopped working.  Effectively a show stopper.  I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202012/aurelia-fetch-client-create-request-headers-on-the-fly?rq=1) and changed the way I implemented headers to the following and it now works.

```
const task = fetch("/api/jwt", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(this.login),
    headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // First save the JWT.
      this.tokenService.saveJWT(data);

      // Next go back to the api and get the username and save that.
      this.userService.saveUserName();

      // Finally redirect to home page.
      this.router.navigate("home");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.tokenService.clearJWT();
    });
```

You will notice that I now add headers using "new":

```
headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' })
```

Comment: not sure why but I have that exact same error but doing the "new Headers" business didn't work for me. I believe its purely a TypeScript error in reference to the fetch api for headers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
export async function GET() {
  const res = await fetch('https://data.mongodb-api.com/...', {
    headers: <any> {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'API-Key': process.env.DATA_API_KEY,
    },
  });
  const data = await res.json();
 
  return NextResponse.json({ data });
```

Comment: The `<any>` did the trick